# Convert x number of days to decimal year

Tags: php

I have a number of X days, let's say 700.
How can I output this 700 to years?
Eg. 700 = 1.11 years (1 year 11 months)
or 2.2 (2 years and two months)
... And so on

I don't care for leap years or such, just need an aproximate value.

Comment: 700 / 365.25? Is this really what you're asking?

Comment: there are 12 months in a year, so 1.11 is not equivalent to 1 year, 11 months...

Comment: Have you tried google? http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet86.htm

Comment: 700/365.25 = 1.92. should be 1.11 (one year DOT eleven months) *I just need a representation of time. 2 years would be 2, not 1.12 as blearn said.
Yea, I've tried google, no results for "days to year" in the format I'm expecting. Why the trolling? This is a question like any other :|

Comment: I never said that 2 years is 1.12!  What I said (in a different form) is that your 1 year 11 months example would be 1 and 11/12 months = 1.916667... This is easy to convert back to actual months later (simply multiply by 12).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think about it...

700 days, 30 days in a month.

700/30 = 23.33 months. 12 months in a year.

23.33/12 = 1.944444... take the integer value `(int)1.944444` to get 1 for the year.

23.33%12= 11.33... months. You can cast it to an int as well to get 11

Your result: 1 year, 11 months

Comment: @KarolyHorvath that's the simplest way (algebra wise) to do the conversion. You can use 30.42 (Wolfram) for days/month if you want... I also cast everything to an int so you lose some information there, too... It's crude but simple.

Answer (score 2):

try this one...

```
//86400 seconds per day
//31556926 seconds per year

$days = 700;

$timestamp = (86400 * $days) / 31556926;

echo $timestamp;
//  = 1.9165364839402 years
```

use this site for referrence: `http://www.epochconverter.com/` they have conversion per month, week, days.
    //1.9165364839402