# Display a given number of days as "#Years, # Months, # Weeks, # Days"

Tags: php, sql, datetime

Using "number of days" from a SQL database, how can I return it in a more human-friendly format?

For example, for many users, this number is pretty high. Instead of them seeing "438 days", I would like to display: "1 year, 2 months, 1 week, 5 days."

Thank you!

Comment: Have You tried anything ?
It's a bit complicated to calculate that with day precision.
Btw, I will go with Modulus operator, first years, than months etc...

Comment: Simple math. `365.25` days in a year. A month averages at `30` days, and a week `7`.

Comment: And don't forget your isLeapYear test. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert x number of days to decimal year](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12925778/convert-x-number-of-days-to-decimal-year)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select floor(yourfield/365) + ' year(s), ' + 
       floor(mod(yourfield,365)/30) + ' month(s), ' + 
       floor(mod(mod(yourfield,365),30)/7) +' week(s), ' + 
       floor(mod(mod(mod(yourfield,365),30),7)) + ' day(s)'
FROM table

assumes + is valid operator in mySQL for string concat.
assumes 1 year = 365 days
assumes 1 month = 30 days
assumes 1 week = 7 days
```

Given we don't know start/end dates taking into account days in month or leap years is an exercise in futility.

Answer (score -2):

You could use `strtotime()` and `DateTime`

```
$time = strtotime("438 days ago");
$past = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d', $time));
$present = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d', time()));
$difference = $past->diff($present);
echo $difference->format('%a days %y years');
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php

Comment: That will output the date 438 days ago, not what the OP requested.

Comment: That will show the date 438 days ago.